# OpenStreetMap tile polygon click detect silently down

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, polygon, openstreetmap

I'm working on the OpenStreetMap for display polygons. Here I'm using `MKMapView` and set tile of OpenStreetMap.

> OSM tile is `http://tile.openstreetmap.org/\(path.z)/\(path.x)/\(path.y).png`

It's working fine and draw the polygon on the accurate position. (please find the attachment below) I have added the `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the polygon which is drawn on the map for getting click event. The only issue is when I tap on the polygon it detects silently down. please check the [video here](https://vimeo.com/392393286).

**Code of tile:**

```
func setupTileRenderer() {
     let overlay = AdventureMapOverlay()
     overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
     mapView.addOverlay(overlay, level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveLabels)
     tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)
     overlay.minimumZ = 13
     overlay.maximumZ = 16
}
extension MapViewVC : MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let overlay = overlay as? myPolygon {
            let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: overlay)
            renderer.fillColor = overlay.color //UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange
            renderer.lineWidth = 2
            return renderer
        }
        return tileRenderer
    }

    func removeMapOverlay(){
        self.mapView.removeOverlays(self.arrPolygons.compactMap({$0.mkOverlay}))
    }
}
```

**Tap event:**

```
@objc func mapTapped(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        let point = gesture.location(in: self.mapView)
        let coordinate = self.mapView.convert(point, toCoordinateFrom: nil)
        //print("Tap \(coordinate)")
        for overlay in self.mapView.overlays {
            if let polygon = overlay as? MKPolygon {
                guard (self.mapView.renderer(for: polygon) as? MKPolygonRenderer) != nil else { continue }
                if polygon.contain(coor: coordinate){
                    print("Tap was inside this polygon \(coordinate)")
                    break
                }                
                continue
            }
        }
    }
extension MKPolygon {
    func contain(coor: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        let polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(polygon: self)
        let currentMapPoint: MKMapPoint = MKMapPoint(coor)
        let polygonViewPoint: CGPoint = polygonRenderer.point(for: currentMapPoint)
        return polygonRenderer.path.contains(polygonViewPoint)
    }
}
```

> P.S.: I'm also finding way to render OpenStreetMap offline line same as MKMapView.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you. :)